# Layering Image over Flash XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, layer

I have a flash UI, and a image. I would like to place the image OVER the flash object, but I can't seem to get it working when using Panel.Zindex.

Here is my Code

```
      <my1:WpfFlashUI Name="mFlashUI" Margin="0,0,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
        <Image Name="img2" Source="http://www.donkersct.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/stackoverflow.png" Height="217" Width="363" Margin="560,199,-45,6" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working, or suggest a better way? I have tried swapping the Zvalues around.

Comment: You can't do this. The real question is why you're using that flash stuff to begin with.

Comment: its a RTMP player. I do not know any other players that i can put into the app that will play RTMP

Comment: [VLC can play RTMP](http://www.jpsaman.org/vlc/rtmp), and it has a (somewhat) native WPF player. Try that.

Comment: The flash player is probably using WinForms controls for visualization. Any WinForm control hosted in WPF will always be on top of other (WPF) elements. The only way to overlay something on such control is to have another window. This window should be transparent, without chrome and it's position/size is manually managed (<--**big** headache here).